# Removing carriage return while splitting a string using split function

Tags: java, string, csv, split

I have a string like

```
String str="second,b,c,d,e,c"
```

When i am splitting this string on regex=","

```
String[] array=str.split(,);
```

I should get

```
array[5]="c".
```

But what I am getting is

```
array[5]="c+carriage return".
```

How to remove this carriage return?

I am getting the string from scanner.
Here's the code:

```
File file=new File(path2);
        Scanner inputstream=new Scanner(file);
        inputstream.useDelimiter("\n");
        while(inputstream.hasNext()){
            String data=inputstream.next();
            String[] val=data.split(",");
            String sql4="insert into "+name+"(question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer) values('"+val[0]+"','"+val[1]+"','"+val[2]+"','"+val[3]+"','"+val[4]+"','"+val[5]+"')";
            s.execute(sql4);
        }
```

File content are second,b,c,d,e,c in .csv format

Comment: It looks like your String is haunted. You should hire an exorcist.

Comment: @MaximShoustin I had posted file content

Comment: @MaximShoustin i have edited question with file content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
String str="second,b,c,d,e,c";
str = str.replaceAll("[\n\r]", "");
String[] array=str.split(",");

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
     System.out.println(array[i]);
```

Comment: What will the second line do??

Comment: Will replace the carriage return and mew line with empty string

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> lines =                          // just quick way to read file
            Files.readAllLines(
                Paths.get("C:\\Automation1\\Example.csv"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    lines.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null)); // <- remove empty lines
    String[] array=lines.get(0).trim().split(",");

    System.out.println(array[5]);
```

Output:

```
c
```

Comment: Sry, i have edited question. This variables were just used as an example.

Comment: please post file content

Comment: I added to remove empty lines if you have, so it will take care only for data

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [String#trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) on your String before spliting it

```
String[] arr = line.trim().split(",");
```